# how to import jms

Tags: java, eclipse, jms

I've just started using my Eclipse to test some jms codes. The thing is... Eclipse uses JRE standard libs; When I write code like a

> import javax.jms.*;

no lib is identified. So my question is how to import jms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the `Java EE` distribution and include it in your build path.

Available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)

If thats too heavyweight for you, you can find a jms.jar which typically contains just the jms client classes needed. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadjmsjar.htm) is one.

Comment: Emm I think I have JDK 6 installed but for some reason it wasn't identified with Eclipse. So what could be wrong?

Comment: In your Eclipse settings, make sure you have the right JDK selected. This automatically adds it to the build path.

Comment: Emm... There are so many JEE versions on oracle.com; I am not pretty sure which one is OK to download in my case. I have JDK 6 installed so which download link to use?

Comment: Thank you. The JEE is really too heavy so I had to find the jms.jar only http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadjmsjar.htm

Comment: Your link to java2s seems to be broken. This points to the javax.jms-*.jar download list: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjmsjar.htm